# Shortcut of app doesn't exit in emulator in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to open this app in emulator, but i dont see shortcut, can somebody check it? Im new in Xamarin and this is not my program

https://github.com/fardage/Fernweh-App

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  This is not an on-topic question

Answer (score 0):

After download the file, run the `Fernweh.sln`. Cick the plus button to add. Search the `New York` in the search bar and click the Next. Finally, click the Done button in top roght. It would generate the screenshot which you want.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any update? Have you soved this issue?